# Self join on different columns in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, self-join

I have pyspark dataframe like this

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    Row(a=1, b=3),
    Row(a=3, b=2),
])

+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  3|
|  3|  2|
+---+---+
```

I tried self-join on it like this

```
df1 = df.alias("df1")
df2 = df.alias("df2")

cond = [df1.a == df2.b]
df1.join(df2, cond).show()
```

But it gives me error.

Ideally i want to find all pair where one neighbor is common. (3 is common to both 1,2)

```
+---+---+
| c1| c2|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
+---+---+
```

Comment: This seems to work: `df2 = df.select(df.a.alias('aa'), df.b.alias('bb'))` and then `df.join(df2, df.a == df2.bb).select(['b', 'aa']).show()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rename column names accordingly before self join.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df_as1 = df.alias("df_as1").selectExpr("a as c1", "b")
df_as2 = df.alias("df_as2").selectExpr("a", "b as c2")
joined_df = df_as1.join(df_as2, col("df_as1.b") == col("df_as2.a"), 'inner').select("c1", "c2")

joined_df.show()
```

Output will be:

```
+---+---+
| c1| c2|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot <3, it worked. I think issue was with using df.a. Using col('df.a') works too.